# Partial round border around an element

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I am trying to achieve this (yellow) without an image:

[image: LCARS Round Border]
The most detailed border-generator I found is [this generator available in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tools/Border-radius_generator).

It doesn't work with it though. **Is there another approach?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved using a combination of an inset `box-shadow` and a `border-radius` on the bottom left hand side.

The `border-radius` on the bottom left side produces the curved bottom side and the inset `box-shadow` produces the colored area. The curvature of the bottom side (both inner and outer) can be increased/decreased by adjusting the `border-radius` on the parent container.

```css
.bordered {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: inset 100px -15px 0px darkorange;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 2px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 11px;
}
/* just for demo */

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered"><span>Schematic</span>
  <span class="bottom-right">1234567890</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @PrimuS: Nice to know that you liked it :)

Answer (score 2):

A slight alternative on @Harry's solution would be to make use of pseudo elements:

```css
.orange {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  background: darkorange;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100px;
}
.orange:before {
  content: "";
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100px;
}
.bot {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

/*Demo purposes only*/
html,body{background:black;}
```

```html
<div class="orange">Hello, world!
  <div class="bot">MORE!!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PrimuS: Harry's solution is still probably the one to go for, this is just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possbile  with CSS3. However, since the `border-radius` is not supported in all browsers, you need to add the browser prefixes. This generator will help you:
http://border-radius.com/

Comment: border radius is well [suported without vendor prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

Comment: `-moz-` isn't needed since FF 3.6 and `-webkit-` since chrome 4 or safari 4

Comment: I know, but that would come afterwards. With the link you gave me, the above is also not possible to generate. If I understand the border-radius thing correctly, the rounding directly under "SCHEMATIC" would be negative? Bottom left is easy, the "inner" rounding is what gets me stuck.